# Why is the functor $S\mapsto$ isomorphism classes of curves of genus $g$ over $S$ not representable?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, functors, representable-functor

Whenever $R_{1}\hookrightarrow R_{2}$ is an injection of rings,
\begin{equation*}
    \operatorname{Hom}(R,R_{1})\hookrightarrow\operatorname{Hom}(R,R_{2})
\end{equation*}
is an injection for any ring $R$. Thus by dualizing
\begin{equation*}
    \operatorname{Hom}(\operatorname{Spec}(R_{1}),\operatorname{Spec}(R))\hookrightarrow\operatorname{Hom}(\operatorname{Spec}(R_{2}),\operatorname{Spec}(R))
\end{equation*}
is an injection as well, and if $X$ is any scheme, by the usual gluing argument so is
\begin{equation*}
    \operatorname{Hom}(\operatorname{Spec}(R_{1}),X)\hookrightarrow\operatorname{Hom}(\operatorname{Spec}(R_{2}),X)\text{.}
\end{equation*}
It follows from this that the moduli functor
\begin{eqnarray*}
    \mathbf{F}_{1}: & \mathcal{Schemes} & \longrightarrow\mathcal{Sets}\\
     & S & \longmapsto\text{$S$-isomorphism classes of genus-$1$ curves over $S$}
\end{eqnarray*}
is not representable: If it were, $\mathbf{F}_{1}(K)\longrightarrow\mathbf{F}_{1}(L)$ would be an injection for any field extension $K\hookrightarrow L$. But if $K$ is a field that is not closed under square roots, i.e. $\exists d\in K:z^{2}-d\in K[z]\text{ is irreducible}$, then for any $a,b\in K$ the elliptic curves $y^{2}=x^{3}+ax+b$ and $dy^{2}=x^{3}+ax+b$ are not isomorphic over $\operatorname{Spec}(K)$ but over $\operatorname{Spec}(L)$, where $L:=K[z]/(z^{2}-d)$ or any field extension thereof. Hence $\mathbb{F}_{1}(K)\rightarrow\mathbb{F}_{1}(L)$ is not injective.

QUESTION: How do I generalize this argument in order to show that for any $g\in\mathbb{N}$ the functor
\begin{eqnarray*}
    \mathbf{F}_{g}: & \mathcal{Schemes} & \longrightarrow\mathcal{Sets}\\
     & S & \longmapsto\text{$S$-isomorphism classes of genus-$g$ curves over $S$}
\end{eqnarray*}

Is there a genus $g$ analogon to "quadratic twist"?

Comment: In genus $0$, you have $\mathbb P^1$-bundles; these exist in arbitrarily high dimension, but the coarse moduli space of genus $0$ curves is of course just a point, so it cannot hope to serve as a classifying space for genus $0$ families. In genus greater than $1$, the key issue is extra automorphisms; there are never more than $84(g-1)$ by a theorem of Hurwitz, but that's enough to cause problems. This is discussed in some detail in Chapter 2 of *Moduli of Curves* by Harris-Morrison.

Comment: @TabesBridges Chapter 2 of *Moduli of Curves* does **not** explain in any détail why fine moduli spaces do not exist for $M_{g}$, they only explain it for $n=1$ and then proceed to construct coarse moduli spaces. What I need is an exact proof why the fine spaces do not exist for any genus $g$.

Comment: There are exercises in genus $3$ that I was thinking could be extended to higher genus, but looking closer you're right; I had somehow forgotten *just how* frustrating this book can be. Have you looked in *Geometry of Algebraic Curves, Vol. 2* by Arbarello, Cornalba, and Griffiths? It's massive, but that's because many complete arguments are actually included.

Comment: @TabesBridges No, I haven't. Are you sure that book is good? But I wished someone could explain it to me here.

Comment: Am I sure it's good? Well, no, I haven't read it in detail besides a couple of sections. But I'm certainly not advising you spend money on it! I googled a bit, and you might want to look at Example 72 on p. 42 of these notes: https://web.math.princeton.edu/~kollar/book/chap1.pdf, and if you go on to Example 74 you can see how some things in Ex. 72 go absolutely haywire if you look at $\mathbb Q$- or $\mathbb R$-points (which is something else that a fine moduli space should play well with).